# Format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'id'

Tags: objective-c, warnings

```
NSString *val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",[settingsMgr performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([[gets objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])]];
```

In the above code I am getting a warning where `settingsMgr` is object class and `gets` is `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: What are you trying to store in `val`?

Comment: show ur code and array data

Comment: As documentation said `performSelector` method returns value of type `id`, but you using '%u' (unsigned int) in string format.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` can't hold standard types (int, float, BOOL, etc), so they're stored wrapped (in `NSNumber` mostly). Try changing `%u` to `%@`.

Comment: Nothing else was wrong on that i tried with another answer it works for me perfectly.Any way thanks for your response.